# Where implement pattern specification

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, specifications

Suppose this usecase:

I want to obtain a customer from Boston who purchased something between march and july this year.

With DDD

1. Use the specification directly in the UI encapsuled in a object to drive it.
2. Implement differents get methods in the Domain to answer at every usecases.
3. Use the specification directly in the UI

Witch implementation should I use ?

Answer (score 6):

Whether you use the [specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) or explicit query methods depends on the nature and variety of queries that you will have. You can start with explicit methods and once the number of combinations becomes unmanageable, create a specification object. Regardless, a repository or query service will handle the query. You can consider using a [read-model](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) to decouple the responsibility of querying from your domain model.

Comment: +1 because i agree with especially the part on creating explicit methods first then when things get wild refactor to specification pattern.